# MVVM progress bar for long backend requests

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF/MVVM application with a datatable and a lot of records. The user is able to select as much records as they want
 to update one or more properties for all records. If the user clicks the update button, my backend will handle the changes and update
  all records in the database. However every change needs to be send to some other systems. The update query itself does not take long at all,
   the changes to the other systems take more time.

So let's say the user selects 2000 rows to update. The users are most of the time impacient and don't like to wait even tho it's only for 3 seconds.
  What i did was the following:

```
if(totalSelectedRows > 1000) { SplitUpdateRequest(); }
else { Update(selectedRows); }
```

I basicly say that if there are more than 1000 rows selected, the update command will split in multiple update commands of 100 rows each.
  So for the 2000 rows, I call the update method 20 times synchronously. After each call, I will know if the update has succeeded.
  I use this knowledge to show a progressbar.
  I Do this because I now some users will just close the application and try again and again, with the result that the backend has to handle to much incoming request.
  This all seems to work as expected, but I do believe that there has to be another solution/way to handle or show some progress for the user to know what is happening. Are there any suggestions to do this in a different way?
  I don't have the possibility to change anything backendwise.

Below my code:

```
    Viewmodel:

    private AsyncRelayCommand updateCommand;
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return updateCommand ?? (updateCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Update));
        }
    }

    private async Task Testing() => await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // If more than 1000 records, then the request will be seperated into multiple synchronous update commands
        if (selectedRecords?.Count() > 1000)
        {
            TotalRequests = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)selectedRecords.Count() / 1000);
            CurrentRequest = 0;
            ProgressPercentage = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalRequests; i++)
            {
                _service.update(selectedRecords);
                CurrentRequest++;
                ProgressPercentage = (int)(((double)CurrentRequest / (double)TotalRequests) * 100);
            }
        }
        else
            _service.update(selectedRecords);
    });

    View:

    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ProgressPercentage, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressPercentage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"/>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: can you influence "the other systems" to make them report back their state?

Comment: also it makes sense to just change your Window.Cursor to Cursors.Wait so the user knows he has to wait and the average user will be able to wait 2 secunds for a progress update to appear or even 5 secunds to finish a task as long as he know the program is working as intendet which is presented to him by the waiting cursor....

Comment: @DenisSchaf My backend just drops the record in a queue for the other system to take care off, So the progress is done for me a soon a all records are dropped in the queue. Maybe I can do something with this? 

And forgot to mention that cursor is indeed loading